# Can Fortran's procedure pointer associate to instance method of deriver-class?

Tags: pointers, fortran, procedure, derived-class

For example:

```
pointer=>this%method
```

How to achieve it? The pointer and the derived-class were defined in different files.

So can't you achieve it like this?

```
pointer=>method
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. Your question should show much more code than just two lines. All entities appearing in your code should be declared. You should explain what kind of problems you hit,like error messages or similar. Finally, please do not use spellings like U for you, it looks bad, this is not a chat.